# Sending messages to every machine in local network using ZMQ pub/sub?

Tags: zeromq, publish-subscribe

I've got 12 "node" embedded machines that I want send a message to from my server machine.  I don't know their IP address, they don't know mine.  Is there a way I can "broadcast" a tcp message over the local network so that they can all receive it on a certain port?

So far, I’ve tried a pub/sub connection with 12 nodes as publishers & the "server" as the subscriber.  I've heard that you can use 0.0.0.0 to listen for all IP addresses incoming, and you can use * to broadcast to anyone who'll listen.

```
#On the "server"
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:{port}")

#On the "node"
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect("tcp://0.0.0.0:{port}")
```

This works great for testing when the publisher & subscriber are the same machine, but fails when executed on different machines (the message is not never received).  What am I doing wrong here?  Might it have something to do with my firewall?

[If it matters, I'm using python 2 on a MacBook and Linux/ARM nodes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ZeroMQ Guide to Peer to Peer networking](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Cooperative-Discovery-Using-UDP-Broadcasts) goes down the line of using raw UDP to discover peers. You're probably going to have to do something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!  UDP broadcasting is the way to go.